# Ms Excel Conditional Formt Text Ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How do I automatically have excel color code the cells in my table, to the legend I have in column I based on the text values? Is there a formula I can use to do this as I do know VB. I don't mind entering a new rule for each color as long as it pulls the correct text in column I and matches it to the table.

```
Table = Cells B2:F13 containing all text values

Column I2:I5 = text "YELLOW,PINK,PURPLE,BLUE" Fill color to be Yellow

Column I7:I10 = text "GREY,TAN,TEAL,MUSTARD" Fill color to be Green

Column I12:I14 = text "GREEN,ORANGE,RED" Fill color to be Orange
```

Comment: You could write yourself a short macro that picked up the CF rule's *Applies to:* range and the background fill from predesignated cells and used them to construct a rule according to very limited criteria options. Anything more than that and you are essentially rewriting the CF Create Rule command which is fairly easy to use already.

Answer (score 0):

First select cell `B2`. In the Conditional Formatting Rules you will need to make 3 rules, one for each fill color. Select the 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format' option. Now we will use Excel's formulas to determine if the text matches the legend. Enter the following formula into the conditional format for `B2`:

`=IFERROR(MATCH(B2,$I$2:$I$5,0),0)>0`

That is the code for matching to the Yellow, Pink, Purple, and Blue keywords. This takes the value in the cell it applies to and looks for it in the legend referenced, if the `match` function finds the text it returns the location in the array, a non-zero number. If `match` doesn't find a match it throws an error, which we catch with the `iferror` function which converts it into a 0. Finally, we compare our result to 0 which gives us the true/false that the conditional format needs.

Note that the first reference `B2` is relative while the match array reference is absolute. This way when we expand the conditional format to cover the whole area it updates the reference to apply to each cell, but not the reference to our legend.

For the other 2 colors simply adjust the match array to the other references.
Then the final step is to go into the conditional formatting rules manager and adjust the 'applies to' range to the full range instead of just B2.